# Would too small of a mountain bike frame cause lower back pain?

Tags: mountain-bike, bike-fit, size

I'm just under 6' 2" and recently got a Large transition patrol. I'm right on the cusp of needing an XL frame. Anyway, I had a Large patrol before and am noticing now as I did then that my lower back gets really tired after a good intense downhill session. My back feels fine pedaling up and around.

I recently had a Large Santa Cruz Chameleon and didn't notice back pain at all. I'm guessing I'm riding quite a bit harder with the full suspension now.

Anyway, I can't quite figure it out. Is there something about the enduro geometry + a frame size that would lead to downhill-induced lower back fatigue/pain? Any thoughts?

I might just need to strengthen my core a bunch. It's odd. I haven't had back pain except with this.

Comment: If you have the good bike still, get an assistant to take clear, well lit photos of you from the side while on the bike, in your normal riding position and then in your attack position.  Do the same with the new bike, keeping everything else the same.  Then compare the photos and see what the differences are visually.  Use a tripod or a table for the camera  so it doesn't move between photos.